# C++ FileRead usage

Tags: c++, text, c++builder

Wanted to add some I/O text file operations to my controller. To write down the parameters I've choosen:

```
    if ( FileExists("plik.txt") == true )
    {

    int text_file = FileOpen("text_file.txt", fmOpenWrite);
    FileWrite(text_file, IntToStr(index_freq).c_str(),2);
    FileWrite(text_file,"\r\n",strlen("\r\n"));
    }
```

But could you show me on that example how do I use FileRead? I know the pattern is

```
    FileRead(iFileHandle, &dRadius, sizeof(double));
```

But can't quite fit it into mine example. Data written into the file are 1 or 2 characters long in one colum, one under another.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use iostream ?

```
std::ofstream ofs ("text_file.txt", std::ofstream::out);

ofs << index_freq <<std::endl;

ofs.close();
```

more information on how to use them [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/)

Answer (score 0):

Since your text lines are variable length, you have to read the file 1 character at a time until you find the line breaks.  For that kind of I/O, it is better to use a `TStringList` or `TStreamReader` object.  `TStringList` will load the entire file and parse the line breaks for you.  `TStreamReader` has a `ReadLine()` method so you can read the file one line at a time. Both classes are declared in `Classes.hpp`.